# ¿Como obtener el texto de una celda solo si tiene cierto id?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de implementar un sistema en donde el usuario solo pueda darle click a ciertos elementos de una tabla, para eso se me ocurrio ponerle un id a los TD, en donde los que tengan el id si sean los que se puedan presionar y los de no, pues no se puedan. Sin embargo no he podido lograrlo, creo tener una idea. aqui el codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
       <title>Untitled</title>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--

function getVal(e) {
       var targ;
       if (!e) var e = window.event;
       if (e.target) targ = e.target;
       else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
       if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
           targ = targ.parentNode;

       alert(targ.innerText);
}

onload = function() {
       var t = document.getElementById("si");

       for ( var i = 0; i < t.length; i++ )
           t[i].onclick = getVal;
}

</script>



<body>

<table><tr>
       <td id="si">1</td>
       <td id="si"> 2</td>
       <td id="no">3</td>
       <td id="no">4</td>
</tr><tr>
       <td id="no">5</td>
       <td id="no">6</td>
       <td id="no">7</td>
       <td id="no">8</td>
</tr><tr>
       <td id="si">9</td>
       <td id="no">10</td>
       <td id="si">11</td>
       <td id="si">12</td>
</tr></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Mi pregunta es ¿será que esta mal redactada la función onload? en esta parte:

```
onload = function() {
       var t = document.getElementById("si");

       for ( var i = 0; i < t.length; i++ )
           t[i].onclick = getVal;
```

Comment: Los ID no se pueden repetir, son únicos en cambio usa clases

Comment: @BetaM ¿Qué tal si haces eso una respuesta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Los `id` funcionan como un identificador único para cada elemento donde lo asignas como atributo, dicho lo anterior entonces deberías usar clases `.nombre-clase`

Además de eso puedes darle una clase al elemento superior que contiene a todas las celdas, que en este caso sería la etiqueta `table`, una vez hecho eso podemos evaluar por medio de *target* quien de los elementos internos de esta etiqueta fue el que *desencadeno* el evento de `click` y a partir de ahi evaluar si contiene la clase deseada y en concecuencia **asignar algún comportamiento**

Con lo anterior de hecho vamos a poder:

- Identificar a que celda le dimos click
- Asignar algún comportamiento solo a las celdas que contengan en su *lista de clases* el valor que le pasemos como *argumento* que en este caso sería la clase **`.si`**
- Estaríamos evitando el uso de ciclos para iterar todos los elementos que contienen dicha clase

**Propuesta**

```html
    <style>
      td {
        border: 1px solid;
      }
    </style>
    <table class="tabla-contenedor">
      <tr>
             <td class="si">1</td>
             <td class="si">2</td>
             <td class="no">3</td>
             <td class="no">4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
             <td class="no">5</td>
             <td class="no">6</td>
             <td class="no">7</td>
             <td class="no">8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
             <td class="si">9</td>
             <td class="no">10</td>
             <td class="si">11</td>
             <td class="si">12</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
      let celdasSi = document.querySelector(".tabla-contenedor")
      
      celdasSi.addEventListener("click", (evento) => {
        if (evento.target.classList.contains("si")) {
          console.log("Aquí si funcionará el click")
        } 
      })
    </script>
```

**EDICIÓN**

Para almacenar en una variable el valor de la celda donde esta la clase **`.si`**, deberás recuperar el **`.innerText`** y asignarlo a dicha variable para que finalmente ser ese el valor que imprimes en el `console.log()`

```html
       <style>
          td {
            border: 1px solid;
          }
        </style>
        <table class="tabla-contenedor">
          <tr>
                 <td class="si">1</td>
                 <td class="si">2</td>
                 <td class="no">3</td>
                 <td class="no">4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                 <td class="no">5</td>
                 <td class="no">6</td>
                 <td class="no">7</td>
                 <td class="no">8</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                 <td class="si">9</td>
                 <td class="no">10</td>
                 <td class="si">11</td>
                 <td class="si">12</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
          let celdasSi = document.querySelector(".tabla-contenedor")
          //variable donde recupèraremos el valor de cada celda que tiene la clase si
          let valorSeleccionado = ""
          
          celdasSi.addEventListener("click", (evento) => {
            if (evento.target.classList.contains("si")) {
              //asignación del texto de cada celda que contiene la clase si
              valorSeleccionado = evento.target.innerText
              console.log(`Aquí si ${valorSeleccionado}`)
            } 
          })
        </script>
```

Comment: wow me encanto tu solución, de verdad agradezco el tiempo que te tomaste en redactarla, y pues no quiero abusar de ti, sin embargo me ha surgido una pregunta mas, ¿como podría guardar en una variable el contenido de la celda? por ejemplo si presiona el 9 y esta en un si, como guardar ese 9 en una variable. Disculpa por el abuso.

Comment: Hecho @ErickCastillo revisa la edición

Comment: Mil gracias, de verdad, usted fue de mucha ayuda!!! Super bien explicado. DE NUEVO MUCHAS GRACIAS

Answer (score 1):

El `id` no es la mejor idea para hacer este tipo de cosas. El `id` debería ser único y hacer referencia a un único elemento en todo el DOM.

El atributo `class` sirve para definir un elemento dentro de un conjunto de elementos con unas misma características. Esto es mayormente usado para el diseño (los estilos, CSS); pero también muy útil a la hora de acceder a ciertos elementos des de nuestro *script*.

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td class="si">1</td>
         <td class="si">2</td>
         <td class="no">3</td>
         <td class="no">4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Así definiríamos las clases para los elementos. Des del script accederíamos con la función `querySelectorAll` del objeto `document`.

```
const tds = document.querySelectorAll('.si');
```

Con el punto (`.`) decimos que queremos acceder a todos los elementos del DOM con la clase `si`.

Te dejo aquí la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), muy útil.

Espero que sirva.